# Could the local .htaccess not behave like the remote one?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wamp, remote-server

I have been given access to some old, functional website with the task of updating some aspect of it.

I told myself I should set up a local copy of the website, do my change and then reupload it.

I have an up-to-date wamp stack and I've set up my host/virtual host to include a fake domain. (website is blabla.com, blabla.loc for localhost).

Some url works, but some don't. I'm pretty sure it's an .htaccess issue, but I can't figure why.

> blabla.com --> works
>   blabla.com/index.php --> 404
>   blabla.com/profil --> works
>   blabla.com/realisations/view --> works
>   blabla.com/realisations/view/1 --> works
>   blabla.com/realisations/add --> works

local

> blabla.loc--> 404
>   blabla.loc/index.php --> 404
>   blabla.loc/profil --> 404
>   blabla.loc/realisations/view --> works  <--
>   blabla.loc/realisations/view/1 --> works
>   blabla.loc/realisations/add --> 404

Here's the .htaccess content :

```
RedirectMatch ^/app/ /

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond $1  !^(images|css|js|fichiers|stats|swf|FAVICON.ICO|robots.txt|.php53.fcgi|phpinfo.php)

    RewriteCond $1  !null
    RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\/\-\_\.\=]*)?$        index.php   [QSA,NC,L]

</IfModule>
```

Note : The application use an homemade MVC pattern...

Comment: Is the remote server *nix?  Have you compared the `httpd.conf` or vhosts configuration (if applicable) in the two environments?

Comment: Yes. No. I do not have access to the remove host httpd.conf afaik (ftp only).

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess? Is it inside `DOCUMENT_ROOT` or `DOCUMENT_ROOT/app/`? Is `index.php` inside `DOCUMENT_ROOT/app/`?

Comment: Both are on the same level and at the root of the web folder. Remote server : `public_html/index.php` and `public_html/.htaccess`. Local server : same, but no public_html folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried updating wamp : It didn't work.

I removed and re-installed wamp : Fixed my problem.

No idea what the actual problem was.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have mod_rewrite loaded. If it's not loaded, the entire block inside the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` container will be ignored. If these rules are ignored, then your requests won't get routed tpo the `index.php` file.

The `httpd.conf` file on your local machine should have a line uncommented that looks something like:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Additionally, make sure that the vhost config for your local setup has the directory of your document root set to allow override. Either "all" or at least "fileinfo":

```
AllowOverride All
```

Comment: The module is loaded, since `blabla.loc/realisations/view` works on localhost. And yes, I have `AllowOverride All`.